# How to differenciate between registered hotkeys using user32.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, user32, global-hotkey

I have registered two Hotkeys

```
RegisterHotKey(thiswindow, (uint) WindowKeys.Alt, 1, (int)Keys.D1); 
RegisterHotKey(thiswindow, (uint) WindowKeys.Alt, 2, (int)Keys.D2);
```

Now how do I differentiate between them using:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message keyPressed)
        {
            if (keyPressed.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                if (alt+d1 is pressed)
                   //do something
                if (alt+d2 is pressed)
                   //do something
            }

            base.WndProc(ref keyPressed);
        }
```

I am doing this inside a WinForm project with user32.dll imported.

Comment: The HotKey ID is passed in WParam, so `int hotKeyID = keyPressed.WParam.ToInt32();`. The Key pressed and the Modifiers are packed in LParam:  `var key = (Keys)(keyPressed.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);` and `var modifier = (KeyModifier)(keyPressed.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFF);`

Comment: @Jimi I tested your solution and it seems to only work with "1" being the key code. Nothing happens with ```RegisterHotKey(thiswindow, (uint) WindowKeys.Alt, 2, (int)Keys.D2);``` being registered

Comment: You should double-check the definition of the RegisterHotKey function.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, first the ID, then the modifier. Thanks for your help